# Is there a transcript or audio recording of the lecture on Riemann Hypothesis by John Nash at Columbia University in 1959 anywhere?

Tags: john-nash, riemann

The film A Beautiful Mind depicts this scene, and it is mentioned on wikipedia as well as many articles/books. John Nash famously gave a lecture to 250 mathemeticians at Columbia University in 1959 eagerly anticipating his potential proof of the Riemann Hypothesis, however it soon became clear from his incoherent speech that he had entered psychosis and was presenting nonsense.

Regardless, I would still like to read/hear what he was saying if that is possible. I have tried searching for transcripts or audio of the lecture to no avail. Is this available anywhere? Thank you.